# Modificar la tabla de AspNetUser para que dependa de otra

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, identity

Yo estoy intentando crear una tabla de la cual dependa el usuario, la idea es que por ejemplo, en un sistema medico, los usuarios que pertenezcan a una compañia (owner), solo puedan ver la información de esa compañía y de esa forma tener una misma base de datos para varias compañias, donde los usuarios se puedan conectar simultáneamente a la misma información.

**Al momento de realizar la migración en ASP NEt Core 2.2** estoy teniendo el siguiente error, y en verdad no tengo idea si lo que intento hacer es posible, pues todos los ejemplos que veo en internet no tienen absolutamente nada que ver con lo que yo deseo hacer.

Error: Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'ApplicationUser.Shop' of type 'Shop'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

Mi estructura

**User**

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser, ISoftDeleted
    {

        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public string Image { get; set; }       

        public bool Deleted { get; set; }     



        public  Shop Shop { get; set; }

        public int ShopId { get; set; }      

    }
```

**Shops**

```
public class Shop : AuditEntity, ISoftDeleted
    {
        //[Key] 
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Address { get; set; }

        public string Email { get; set; }

        public string Tel { get; set; }       

        public bool Deleted { get; set; }

        // [JsonIgnore]

        public Owner Owner { get; set; }

        public int OwnerId { get; set; }

    }
```

**Company**

```
public class Owner :AuditEntity, ISoftDeleted

    {    
       // [Key]    
        public int Id { get; set; } 

        public string Code { get; set; }    

        public string Name { get; set; } 

        [Display(Name = "Correo")]

        public string Email { get; set; }

        public string Tel { get; set; }

        public string Prefix { get; set; }   

        public string PrefixFact { get; set; }    

        public string PrefixOrder { get; set; }

        public string PrefixNcf { get; set; }    

        public string PrefixFinalFact { get; set; }

        public string NcfEnds { get; set; }
        public int SeqNcf { get; set; }   

        public int SeqFact { get; set; }

        public bool IsAutoPay { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        public bool Deleted { get; set; }

        //public  ICollection<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set;}
        //public  ICollection<Shop> Shops { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: ¿Ya realizaste la respectiva migración y actualización de base de datos?

Comment: haciendo la migracion es que me da ese error

Comment: dejame editarlo para hacer el aclarando

Comment: Tampoco haces mención de la versión de ASP .NET Core que estás trabajando. Es importante, algunos paquetes se están actualizando en estos días con frecuencia y las instrucciones pueden no ser las mismas entre la 2.1 y la 2.2

Comment: Cierto, la version es la 2.2 de netcore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acuerdo con la [documentación oficial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-2.2#add-navigation-properties), debes realizar 3 pasos:

1. Definir la propiedad de navegación en tu modelo (cosa que ya tienes, creo que está bien).
2. Crear una migración donde modifiques tu modelBuilder para agregar la llave foránea o también puedes hacerlo en el OnModelCreating desde el inicio.
3. Actualizar tu base de datos aplicando la migración respectiva.

Código de ayuda (no necesariamente está bien porque lo estoy haciendo desde el teléfono pero te puede servir de guía):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>(b =>
        {
            b.HasOne(e => e.Shop)
                .WithMany(s => s.ApplicationUsers)
                .HasForeignKey(s => s.Id)
                .IsRequired();
        });
```

También puedes definir la regla alrevés, es decir, desde Shop con HasMany y WithOne para que se parezca al ejemplo que menciona el documento (creo que sería lo ideal).

[Más información](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/fluent-api/hasone-method)

Comment: haciendolo de esta forma se me corrigio el error, pero ahora me arroja el siguiente

The relationship from 'ApplicationUser.Shop' to 'Shop.ApplicationUsers' with foreign key properties {'Id' : string} cannot target the primary key {'ShopId' : int} because it is not compatible. Configure a principal key or a set of compatible foreign key properties for this relationship.

Comment: error de capa 8, sorry

Comment: Ahí es por el tipo de dato. Qué bien que el error anterior ya se corrigió :)